# cannot reach Windows 7 RC product key page

Tags: windows-7

I was going to install 7 RC (as long as it won't be possible in few days) - but I'm not able to get to the product key page. All i get is this error:

"betaexperience scripts gcs aspx" cannot be reached

and then I'm redirected to bing search/

Comment: superuser please?

Answer (score 1):

The period for RC download is closed. If it's just the key you're after, follow the steps at http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-7/get/download.aspx.

**edit**: I just followed the steps and get the same error. Looks like the page is now down. Windows 7 is released in about a week and the download hasn't been available for a month or more.

Comment: have the ISO at home, I just need the key - but following the instructions ends in the error I presented in the post...

Answer (score 0):

See this page : [Get Windows 7: Windows 7 RC](https://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-7/get/download.aspx). It says:

> Sorry, the Windows 7 RC is no longer
>   available for download. If you’ve got
>   the download and need a product key,
>   they’ll be available **until October 21 2009**.

So hurry!

Comment: wtf guys? - you can't read? - i wrote about not being able to get the product key, and there are 2 answers telling me that i can't download the ISO - hey wake up - i commented on the first answer that i have ISO, so why the next answer is once more telling me i cannot download it?

Comment: STOP SWEARING AND START READING! This is for getting the key, NOT the iso !!!!!

Comment: did you try getting one? - i did - and that's the problem - the website is down not functioning

Comment: It was working when I posted this. Keep trying. You have (apparently) until October 21 2009.

Answer (score 0):

OK, finally using firefox I got the key, so the site might have been down for some time today - I was trying since morning using IE8, FF and Opera.

Comment: @rezna, suggest you close the question as no longer relevant (or delete it) since this was obviously just a temp glitch at the Microsoft site - I guess that's the price you pay for using IIS :-)